# appending specific words to list from file in python

Tags: python

---

I am writing a program that reads from a file of 50,000 words and it needs to get the percentage of words that do not have the letter 'e' in them. I can get the program to print all the words without e's but I want to append them to a list so that I can get the sum of the elements within the list. What I have now gives me the result of 0 every time I run it. It also produces the total amount of lines which is correct. Sorry, I am not the best in python.

```
f=open("hardwords.txt")

def has_no_e(f):
    words = []
    sum_words= len(words)
    total = sum(1 for s in f)
    print total
    print sum_words
    letter = 'e'
    for line in f:
        for l in letter:
            if l in line:
                break
        else:
            words.append(line)

has_no_e(f)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to collect the words, just count them.

Untested:

```
total = 0
without_e = 0
with open("hardwords.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        total = total + 1
        if not 'e' in line:
            without_e = without_e + 1

percentage = float(without_e) / float(total)
```

Comment: You think of each line being a word. The OP did not mention that.

Comment: @Bharel The OP did not provide *any* input sample. We can assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
def has_no_e():
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        words = [word.strip() for line in f.readlines() for word in line.strip().split(',')]
        words_without_e = [word for word in words if 'e' not in word]
        print len(words), words
        print len(words_without_e), words_without_e

has_no_e()
```

Now you just need to calculate the percentage

Answer (score 0):

This does just so:

```
def has_no_e(path):
    total_words = 0
    words_without_e = 0
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.lower().split()
            total_words += len(words)
            words_without_e += sum("e" not in w for w in words)

    return (float(words_without_e)/total_words)*100
```

Comment: `len(<generator expression>)` will error out.  Generator expressions don't have a length.  Use something like `sum("e" not in w for w in words)` instead if you want to avoid building a temporary list that you don't really need.

Answer (score 0):

This a possible way to do it:

```
with open('G:\Tmp\demo.txt', 'r') as f:
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        total = total + len(words)
        count = count + len([w for w in words if w.find('e') > 0])

print 'Total word:{0}, counted:{1}'.format(total, count)
```